# How to control a UIViewController's view frame

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a view controller like this:

```
MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Obviously I want the view to be sized to 0,0,320,300.

However, viewDidLoad gets called before the frame gets set, and thus in viewDidLoad I get this:

```
<UIView: 0x155d3180; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x155c20c0>>
```

So the views in the new view controller get laid out based on a height of 568 instead of the 300 that I want. What can I do to prevent this new view from being created with the wrong frame size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calling of `viewController.view` (followed by `.frame`) is what triggers the call to `viewDidLoad`.

The proper solution is to layout the subviews in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of your view controller, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to get a proper size in the new ViewController `viewDidLoad`. The view frame init just when you call `viewController.view`. when will call  the new ViewController `loadView` where the view will init with frame(0 0; 320 568) and then `viewDidLoad`, so where you call `view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);` is too later for your layout in `viewDidLoad`.

you can try this in the new ViewController `loadView`:

```
- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);
}
```

If you want to set frame outside, you can add a `initFrame` property and a new init method for the new ViewController:

```
- (id)initWithMyFrame:(CGRect)myFrame{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.myInitFrame = initFrame;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
    self.view.frame = self.myInitFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, viewDidload call when load xib file. It still has default size. This is result a test for changing size(on iPad screen):

```
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} viewDidLoad
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} viewWillAppear:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {768, 1004}} willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} viewWillLayoutSubviews
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} layoutSubviews
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} viewDidLayoutSubviews
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
{{0, 0}, {1024, 748}} viewDidAppear:
```

As you can see,view frame in viewDidLoad not exactly.

Second, I think your code work well. Maybe you should check other code in MyViewController

Answer (score 0):

What about calling

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,300);
```

in the ViewDidLoad of  MyViewController